# Wpf событие Click

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть задание выполнить что-то по клику мышкой на этом элементе. Элемент должен быть не Button. Какой элемент лучше всего использовать и какое событие будет подходящим в данном случае?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Элемент может быть любой, проще всего использовать какой-нибудь потомок `ContentControl`, например `Label`. В качестве события можно использовать, например, `MouseLeftButtonUp` или `MouseLeftButtonDown`.

Answer (score 1):

Прямое рисование мышью удобно осуществить с помощью элемента [InkCanvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.inkcanvas.aspx). В этом случае одного этого элемента будет достаточно для простого рисования:

```
<InkCanvas height="100" width="100" />
```

Comment: Вы меня неправильно поняли) я имел ввиду рисовать не мышкой по контролу, а из кода сразу какую-нибудь готовую фигуру)